# signing exe with SSL certificate using eclipse tycho

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, code-signing, tycho

I would like to use our code-signing SSL certificate to sign our product exe which is an eclipse RCP application and is built with [eclipse tycho](https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho).

Is there an official way to do this? There seems to be a [sign-p2-artifacts-mojo](https://tycho.eclipseprojects.io/doc/latest/tycho-gpg-plugin/sign-p2-artifacts-mojo.html) plugin, but I can't find an example.

I found this [example (servoy-eclipse)](https://github.com/Servoy/servoy-eclipse/blob/master/com.servoy.eclipse.product/pom.xml#L51) which uses [jsign](https://github.com/ebourg/jsign), but I would prefer not to interfere with the default tycho build process (publisher, director). I also try to stay pom-less at the bundle level (where the product file lays).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.jsign</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsign-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>sign</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <file>${project.build.directory}/tosign/servoy.exe</file>
                <name>Servoy</name>
                <url>http://servoy.com</url>
                <keystore>${jarsigner.keystore}</keystore>
                <alias>${jarsigner.alias}</alias>
                <storepass>${jarsigner.storepass}</storepass>
                <tsaurl>http://timestamp.sectigo.com,http://timestamp.digicert.com,${jarsigner.tsa}</tsaurl>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: `sign-p2-artifacts-mojo` is for PGP signing JARs, not for code-signing an executable. As far as I know, the process of code-signing an executable differs depending from where you have your code-signing certificate. Maybe you can do it in a post-processing step via the maven-antrun-plugin.